# C# GetValue from JSON

Tags: c#, node.js, json, json.net

I have a NodeJS Server and a C# Unity Client.  The NodeJS server sends an object to the C# client.

**SERVER**

```
        var obj = new Object();
        obj.name = data.name;
        obj.position  = data.position;
        var jsonString= JSON.stringify(obj);
```

**C# Client**

```
            try
            {
                Debug.Log(response.ToString()); // WORKS the result is
                /*
                [
                   {
                      "name": "Peter",
                      "position": "(13.6, 1.5, 2.3)"
                   }
                ]
                */

                Debug.Log(response.GetValue(1).ToString()); // Don't work, receive in console (ERROR).
            }
            catch
            {
                Debug.Log("Error");
            }
```

Output

```
            [
               {
                  "name": "Peter",
                  "position": "(13.6, 1.5, 2.3)"
               }
            ]
```

So I try to read the JSON to get the Value Name and Position.

I have already tried the following:

```
string resVal1 = response.GetValue<string>();
Enemy resVal2 = response.GetValue<Enemy>(1);


string enemyName= response.GetValue(1).Value<string>("name");
```

Source:
https://github.com/doghappy/socket.io-client-csharp

I also only get "Error" here. What am I doing wrong? How do I get name and position from the JSON string. I have not much experience with JSON.

Comment: First suggestion: stop swallowing exceptions. The reason you're only seeing "Error" in the console is because you're saying "If anything goes wrong, I don't need any of the information in the exception - I'll throw it all away". I suggest you remove the try/catch entirely, and just let the exception bubble up. Then you can edit your post with a [mcve] (we don't even know the type of `response` at the moment) including the full stack trace. Oh, and include the JSON you're receiving, too.

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet
thank you for your feedback. I cannot remove Try and Catch. If I do, I don't get a server message either. The only thing that happens is that the server connection is interrupted. In Unity I have no error message. 

I have already included the JSON that the client receives in the source code above. I have also packed it extra for you.

Comment: At very least we need to know what `response` is.

Comment: Have you tried `string enemyName= response.GetValue(0).Value<string>("name");` ? Arrays are 0-based

Comment: Hi @Jamiec 
I would like to find that out too.
I used the following Socket IO project as reference https://github.com/doghappy/socket.io-client-csharp
It also says // You can get the JSON string of the response by calling response.ToString() 
Unfortunately I am a little bit perplexed

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/doghappy/socket.io-client-csharp/blob/master/src/SocketIOClient/SocketIOResponse.cs

Comment: @Jamiec Oh WoW!!! It works... Okay for trying for three hours, it was very simple.

Comment: "If I do, I don't get a server message either." Not sure what you mean by that, but if you really can't diagnose exceptions, I would treat *that* as the most important problem right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON returned is an array with a single element, that element is an object with 2 properties - one of which is `name` so I suspect he correct code to read that would be:

```
string enemyName= response.GetValue(0).Value<string>("name");
```